# Problem pageable in spring boot using JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

if the size is larger than the number of records, my object Page returns empty.

parameters: size=100&page=1

```
{
    "content": [],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 100,
        "pageSize": 100,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalElements": 69,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "last": true,
    "size": 100,
    "number": 1,
    "numberOfElements": 0,
    "first": false,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "empty": true
}
```

How to return only the records found?

tks!

Comment: Hi @richardo I will help you please help more about what you trying to  here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, in the Spring Data, by default, the page number is started from 0.
And you try to get page=1 (this is the second page).